# Meteor deploy with node-prerender failed

Tags: meteor, seo, prerender

I would like deploy my Meteor APP with `node-prerender` but it failed on 'Verifying Deployment' with `mup`.

I've not any error, just failed :

```
- Verifying Deployment
[   [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] x Verifying Deployment: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    ib/src/blowfish.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
      SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
      COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
    make: Leaving directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
    bcrypt@0.8.7 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
    bindings@1.2.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bindings
    nan@2.3.5 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/nan

    > buffertools@2.1.4 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bufferstream/node_modules/buffertools
    > node-gyp rebuild

    make: Entering directory '/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bufferstream/node_modules/buffertools/build'
      CXX(target) Release/obj.target/buffertools/buffertools.o

    => Redeploying previous version of the app

    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If i test to deploy my APP without node-prerender, it work nice.

I'm based on [this blog post](https://juststartworking.com/meteor-and-seo-the-right-way/).

My JS call in server :

```
Meteor.startup(() => {

  const prerenderio = Npm.require('prerender-node');
  const settings = Meteor.settings.private.PrerenderIO;

  if (settings && settings.token && settings.host) {
    prerenderio.set('prerenderToken', settings.token);
    prerenderio.set('host', settings.host);
    prerenderio.set('protocol', 'http');
    WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(prerenderio);
  }

});
```

I've not error on local.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: I don't see anything about prerender-node in that error. I only see something about bufferstream, which prerender-node doesn't use. Are there any other errors?

Comment: Hi ! Nop, i don't have any other errors. But if i drop prerender, mup deploy work nice :(